# To pivot a multiple column data frame in R, into one column, and splitting the original column name

Tags: r, pivot

My data is a more complex but simplified it basically looks like this. Each row has only one Yes in one of the multiple Color:* columns. The "Color" before the colon needs to be the new column name, with the named color "Blue", "Red", or "Green" after the colon pivoted under "Color" to the correct "IDENTITY" I forgot to mention there are variable columns before and after these multiple columns I want to pivot into one column. the columns I want to pivot all have the same name before the colon.

| IDENTITY | Color:Blue | Color:Red | Color:Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |  |  |
| 3 |  | Yes |  |

and what I would like is to pivot to this

| IDENTITY | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Green |
| 2 | Blue |
| 3 | Red |

I am not sure if this is a pivot problem. I have read through the tidyr pivot documentation at

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

I do not see a similar example or able to identify one of the solutions that might work with my supplied data.

Can anyone help me with a code chunk I can follow to solve what seems on the face of it a simple problem, but eludes my limited proficiency with R. Thank you and Seasons Blessings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the `pivot_longer` function. This will gather columns and turn them into rows.

**Note**: I had to put ``` `` ``` in front of the column names since `:` is one of those pesky reserved characters in R. You want to avoid having that as a column separator ( `_` could be a useful substitution). You can't always control this, but it's just something to look out for.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- tribble( ~IDENTITY, ~`Color:Blue`, ~`Color:Red`, ~`Color:Green`,
              1L, "", "", "Yes",
              2L, "Yes", "", "",
              3L, "" , "Yes", "")

x %>%
  rename_with(stringr::str_replace,
              pattern = "Color:",
              replacement = "") %>%
  pivot_longer(!IDENTITY,
               names_to = "Color") %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  select(!value)
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, unfortunately the variables in the real life datasets are many and there are a number of variable columns before and after the pesky Color:* columns. rewriting the column names is not going to work, thank you again, Joe

Comment: Adrian your code actually worked, except I had rows without any colors and they were omitted from the data frame. Also I removed the Color: from the data export so I just have the named colors. I omitted the first part of your code that did the same thing. Thank you.

Comment: If they are just color names, then you must choose whether there are more columns that have colors or if there are more columns that don't have colors. I just did `!IDENTITY`  since that was the only one that we didn't need to select, but we could have just as easily selected the other columns explicity. If you don't have the colon then you don't need the names_sep argument and you can just get rid of the last two lines since that is handled by values_drop=TRUE.

Comment: You have to choose what to do with the rows that do not have any color information. How are they being used in this data? They wouldn't have an associated color so they don't technically "exist". Tidyr uses the group_by command to address these issues. Without seeing the rest of the data it would be harder to parse out what exactly you're looking for. I would also suggest joining the r4ds (r 4 data science) slack and ask there everyone is super helpful!

Answer (score 2):

We may convert the blanks (`""`) to `NA`, in `character` columns by looping `across` the character columns, then reshape to 'long' by selecting the `cols` that have column names `starts_with` "Color:"

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(.x, ""))) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Color:"), names_to = c(".value", "Color2"), 
     names_sep = ":", values_drop=TRUE) %>% 
  select(IDENTITY, Color = Color2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  IDENTITY Color
     <int> <chr>
1        1 Green
2        2 Blue 
3        3 Red
```

Comment: Akron thank you I think this was what I was looking for. I have two questions though, you lost me on the first line of code beginning with the mutate function can you explain what that is doing. I get that the -IDENTITY call leaves that column alone, can you show me how to gather all the Color: columns to execute the Pivot_longer call as I forgot to mention in the initial post there are variable columns before and after these pesky Color:* columns. Thank you so much, Joe

Comment: Akrun what would the code look like if the column names were just color names without Color: The code did not work with my data but I can get an export without Color: preceding the color name. Thanks again

Comment: @JosephHarvard It depends on whether youhave any pattern in column names. `Color:` was a common pattern. Or else you can either use index of columns i.e. `cols = 2:5` or if the columns are all adjacent, then the names range from the first column name of color to last i.e. `cols = Blue:Green`